# Bayesian Information Criteria variable penalisation for increasing N

Tags: model-selection, bic, regularization

I am trying to understand the Bayesian Information Criteria for model performance, given by the formula below:

***BIC=−2ln(L)+kln(n)***

I understand the aim is to minimize this function. I can see that the penalization factor kln(n) is increasing in n (the sample size). What is the intuitive reason for penalizing the inclusion of additional variables more heavily for bigger values of n?

Thanks a lot.